# Python JSON - Get how many results based on "category"

Tags: python, json, csv

```
 [       
 {
    "account" : "",
    "address" : "D8xWhR8LqSdSLTxRWwouQ3EiSnvcjLmdo6",
    "category" : "send",
    "amount" : -1000.00000000,
    "fee" : -0.00000001,
    "confirmations" : 716,
    "blockhash" : "4569322b4c8c98fba3ef4c7bda91b53b4ee82d268eae2ff7658bc0d3753c00ff",
    "blockindex" : 2,
    "blocktime" : 1394242415,
    "txid" : "45b629a779e6e0bf6d160c37833a27f1f2cc1bfa34632d166cccae83e69eb6fe",
    "time" : 1394242259,
    "timereceived" : 1394242259
    },
    {
    "account" : "",
    "address" : "DCPFe1fs7qScDFvoTexYqo95LmnJJkjmu7",
    "category" : "receive",
    "amount" : 0.13370000,
    "confirmations" : 717,
    "blockhash" : "e9024e177b42ca23fed741fb90c39836de5f9c722a93157e50df2e3f2c318d77",
    "blockindex" : 26,
    "blocktime" : 1394242412,
    "txid" : "ce41b4c35b09ae582436b8138d62375840c32bd9ea0360457bd9f589012d2da3",
    "time" : 1394242315,
    "timereceived" : 1394242315
    },
    {
    "account" : "",
    "address" : "DCPFe1fs7qScDFvoTexYqo95LmnJJkjmu7",
    "category" : "receive",
    "amount" : 0.00100000,
    "confirmations" : 692,
    "blockhash" : "17eb2ef40b8bcb2ceb3d7f07d6545f03fc9bf41c8d28f759becd84a31e65e123",
    "blockindex" : 14,
    "blocktime" : 1394243788,
    "txid" : "2b099fd0ce6239c5c3c69e2ba70669c3069858908e42b8ca970bf213e555d715",
    "time" : 1394243669,
    "timereceived" : 1394243669
    },
    {
    "account" : "",
    "address" : "DCPFe1fs7qScDFvoTexYqo95LmnJJkjmu7",
    "category" : "send",
    "amount" : -0.00100000,
    "fee" : -2.00000000,
    "confirmations" : 692,
    "blockhash" : "17eb2ef40b8bcb2ceb3d7f07d6545f03fc9bf41c8d28f759becd84a31e65e123",
    "blockindex" : 14,
    "blocktime" : 1394243788,
    "txid" : "2b099fd0ce6239c5c3c69e2ba70669c3069858908e42b8ca970bf213e555d715",
    "time" : 1394243669,
    "timereceived" : 1394243669
    }
    ]
```

That ^^ is my data.

How am I able to see how many "entries" there are where the "category" == "receive"

I want to do this so I can correctly iterate through them all (using a while loop and an interment)

Is there a better way of doing what I want?

I know with a csv I can do

```
for row in reader
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a generator expression like this, and the result of the expression can be fed to the `sum` function to get the total number of entries which have `category` as `receive`

```
sum(item["category"] == "receive" for item in my_list_of_dicts)
```

This is almost equivalent to

```
result = 0
for item in my_list_of_dicts:
    if item["category"] == "receive":
        result += 1
```

**Edit:** If you are reading from the file, then you should load the json data like this

```
import json
my_list_of_dicts = json.load(open("Input.txt"))
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: 
if item["category"] == "receive":
TypeError: string indicies must be integers, not str

Edit: if i were going to get the contents of category, i'd do it like so: ["category"][index_goes_here]

Comment: @Andy The entire data you have shown in the question is a list only, right?

Comment: I think it's a list. It's being returned to me as JSON which I write/read from a file called text.json